# Not an editor command: PluginInstall after new Vundle installation on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-10, vundle

I am trying to setup [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim) on Windows 10 (Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.630) and, after following [these](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows) steps **exactly** (install `git` and `curl` from `chocolatey`, install `gVim` from [here](https://www.vim.org/download.php), clone `Vundle`) I am unable to use `PluginInstall` and instead get the following error: `Not an editor command: PluginInstall`. I can run `vim` and can confirm that a `_vimrc` exists at `C:\Users\myusername\_vimrc` and the `_vimrc currently contains (straight from the docs):

```
filetype off
set shellslash
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('~/vimfiles/bundle')
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Comment: it seems like your _vimrc is not loaded as you expect. Try to add some debug in it. e.g. `echom "HELLO"`. Then use `:msg` to confirm that the text was in fact echoed.

Comment: hi, i am afraid i do not understand your suggestion. where am i to add this line? in the `_vimrc`? I did so by sticking `echom "HELLO"`
before `call vundle#end()` in the `_vimrc` but do not know how to trigger this script to run. or phrased differently: where do i run `:msg`?

Comment: You can use the command `:scriptnames` in Vim to see all the scripts loaded by Vim. You can use that to confirm which `_vimrc` file was loaded by Vim and also to check that the Vundle scripts have been properly loaded.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated... But I tend to strongly recommend using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a more modern alternative to Vundle. It's more well maintained and it has more features and better performance. Yet, it's similar to Vundle in how it works, so if you know Vundle or see instructions for setting something up on Vundle, it's pretty easy to translate them to vim-plug. I really suggest that you adopt vim-plug, especially if you haven't started with Vundle yet!

Comment: @filbranden have given up on Vundle and am now stuck on tryin to install vim-plug LOL

Comment: @caseyanderson Ask a question about it, describe what you tried to do and what worked and what didn't, I'd be happy to help. Post output of `:scriptnames` if you have any issues related to a command not working (same as here.) Also, you might want to head to [vi.se], which is specific on Vim, you might get more help quickly over there.